# Document based application crashes when switching between windows

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, exception, gdb

I'm trying to construct a document based application for Cocoa using Xcode 4 and have encountered a strange issue.

All I have done so far is create an empty document based application. I checked the "Use Core Data", "Use Automatic Reference Counting", "Include Unit Tests" and "Include Spotlight Importer" options.

I can run the application OK but when I switch to another application (e.g. Finder), the following GDB exception comes up in the main function.

> Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Could you edit the question and post the stack trace?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no stack trace. It just crashes out to the main function with that exception in a popup. Btw, I added clarification to my question - it happens as soon as my app loses focus rather than when it regains focus.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that whenever you switch to another window, the application tries to save itself and to restore all data when not idle.
But you haven't given a real implementation of the methods:

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
```

Truly there is the implementation, but the default behaviour for the newest version of xcode is that it throws an exception because the methods are not really implemented.
All you have to do is to refuse the autosave in place:

```
+ (BOOL)autosavesInPlace
{
    return NO;  // it won't try to autosave when you switch to another window
}
```